# Javascript + Rails Form + Modal | Tick checkbox when modal terms 'accepted'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Could someone please tell me why my script isn't working: (wanting to tick a checkbox on a from when the  button click on the popup modal)

```
<script>
$("#updateTerms").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("terms").checked = true;
});
</script>
```

in modal :

```
< button id="updateTerms" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">I agree</button>
```

in form :

```
<%= f.check_box :terms, :id => "terms", :label => "Terms" , :class => 'checkbox'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code: `document.getElementById('terms')` will match the *first* input with that id.  Could there possibly be more than one?

Try this in your browser console:

```
$('#terms')
```

or...

```
$('#terms').length
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - ran $('#terms').length - there's only one!

Answer (score 0):

modify your js and try
**jQuery 1.6+**

Use the new .prop() function:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

The .prop() function is not available, so you need to use .attr().

To check the checkbox (by setting the value of the checked attribute) do

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

and for un-checking (by removing the attribute entirely) do

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```